# Android: ImageButton and Textview not disappearing

Tags: android

I have a layout with several ImageButton and TextView set to Invisible at sartup.

Then on onResume call, I need to parse some variable and make some of this button visible.
This works the first time, but once a button is made visible, all the calls to setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) done on onResume are ignored, so buttons remains visible.
If I restart the app, all the variables are processed correctly.

I guess I need to "reset" in some way the layout, but I didn't undersood how...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can get rid of the ImageViews (better design for performances), by including the images as **compound drawables** inside your TextViews. `all the calls to setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) done on onResume are ignored, so buttons remains visible.` It stinks like some **variables remaining set to the old values**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)  you need to used [ongloballayoutlistener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html)
. It will call after all view initialize in layout.

Answer (score 0):

You put me in the right direction: I was checking the variables to be != "". I had the doubt that this was not evaluated correctly. I changed it to var.length() != 0 and now it get it correctly. Thanks for helping!